# Where can I find an authoritative test suite for the HTML5 standard?

Tags: html, testing, test-suite

I'm looking to write a comprehensive test-suite, to test a set of parsing and processing libraries against the HTML5 standard.

Where can I find an authoritative, comprehensive, suite of tests, which cover the majority of the HTML5 standard?

I've been searching for rendering tests in particular, but any kind of tests will do - as long as they include a set of html source code which exercises most, if not all, of the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official web platform test suite is on GitHub](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests).  Be warned that it's not yet finished, one of the requirements for HTML5 moving from Proposed Recommendation to Recommendation is to complete the test suite so that at least two interoperable implementations can be identified.  Details of [how to submit new tests](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Webapps/Submitting_tests#Test_Review_and_Approval_Workflow) are available on the wiki.